# Inline function hack just to use inline if else

Tags: python, python-3.x

A recent question made me think if it is possible to do something like:

```
def defA(flag) : 
    return "value = 'yes'" if flag else "continue"

flag = False
#n can be a reasonable number like 100
for x in range(n):
    #some logic that may change the flag
    exec(defA(flag))
```

here, you got a variable assignment if the flag is true, or continue the for loop otherwise, but it gives me an odd error:

```
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

Is it possible or should I let it go?

Comment: Please let it go... note that `if flag: value = 'yes'` should work on one line, but it still makes it hard to read control flow.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I agree with you, the duplicated question answered my question, thanks for comment anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because exec doesn't carry the context over to the statement being executed.

pass can be used anywhere, so the context doesn't matter. continue can only be used in the context of a loop, but that context is not available to exec.

You can only use continue in an exec statement if the loop itself is also part of the executed code:

> f = 'for x in range(n): if(flag) continue'   exec f

In other words, you can only use exec for complete statements, where a single continue (or break) is not complete.